# How to grep the number of a specific character in every line of a file

Tags: bash, grep

So I am looking to grep the number of a given character in every line of a very very large file (50Gb). I need to get output for each line that contains the Character ? or . the number of occurrences per line as well as the line number.  Any ideas on how to do this simply from bash?  I know the max number of either char is 10 per line, min is 0.   This is from a old, poorly written custom DB that I need to transform and the original dev used the periods and question marks as delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

The following `awk` command will print the line number, the number of `?`s found and the contents of the line containing the `?`:

```
awk -F? '/?/{print NR,NF-1,$0}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This will output a line-by-line count of `?` or `.` chars in the file preceeded by the line number:

```
line_no=1;
while read line
do
    echo $line_no $((`echo $line | sed 's/[^?.]//g' | wc -m`-1))
    line_no=$(($line_no+1));
done < "your_file.txt"
```